# Div Vertical Align Issue

Tags: css, html, position, margin, vertical-alignment

How can I set center for main div ? I will try many ways but I can't do it. Left and right seem okay. How can I change vertical position property ? I tried these:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;

vertical-align:middle;
```

These do not work.

```
#main 
 {
    width:1024px;
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin:auto auto;
    text-align: center;


 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example (using method 2 of the tutorial below): http://jsfiddle.net/heAXR/1/

This is a good tutorial, it shows several ways of centering your content vertically:
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

I'm a fan of method 3 described in the article, here's a demo:
http://douglasheriot.com/tutorials/css_vertical_centre/demo5.html

Comment: hey, Thanks for attention. I'm trying second method because it's proper for me. But it doesn't work. I have one div and I must set to center it, thats all. I don't want to working with another div. (forexample method 3 has two div)

Comment: This is an example of method 2, with which you only need one div: http://jsfiddle.net/heAXR/ If the centered content is inside another div (which is in 9 out of 10 cases) make sure the parent div has position: relative in it's css for it to work.

Comment: Re-read your question. Here's an example in which the div is centered horizontally and vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/heAXR/1/

Answer (score 1):

May be this tutorial will help you

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are `margin: 0px auto;` solution to align a div horizontally equal.You can use jquery to do vertically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var height = $(window).height();
   var width = $(window).width();
   var mainHeight = $('#main').height();
   var mainWidth = $('#main').width();
   $('#main').css({"top" : height/2 - mainHeight/2 }).css({ "left" : width/2 - mainWidth/2});
});
```